# Correcting implementation of a Factory Method with parameters

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I'm making a solution for a program that builds robots with different types of parts(C#). 
In this case I have two types that share some attributes and both types of part inherit from an abstract class Part.

Until now I was calling new from the actual button code in my interface window and It was something like this.

```
if (type == acuatic)
  Part pieceA = new AcuaticPart(type,name,price,maxDepth);
else
  Part pieceB = new TerrestrialPart(type,name,price,terrain,maxTemp);
```

I know this is totally wrong design and I should be implementing a Factory Method. The thing is I don't know if it's Ok to just send all the parameters to the factory like this:

in the interface window:

```
Part piece = _partFactory.CreatePart(type,name,price,maxDepth,terrain,maxTemp);
```

in the concrete factory:

```
public class ConcretePartFactory : PartFactory
{
    public override Part CreatePart(type,name,price,maxDepth,terrain,maxTemp)
    {
        Part myPart = default(Part);
        switch (type) 
       {
            case "actuatic":
                myPart = new AquaticPart(type,name,price,maxDepth);
                break;
            case "terrestrial":
                myPart = new TerrestrialPart(type,name,price,terrain,maxTemp);
                break;
        }
        return myPart;
    }
}
```

The thing is I still have to pass all the attributes and I think this isn't following the open/closed principle, what can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: assignign myPart = default(myPart) should be in the default of your case statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try overload the factory method with different signatures corresponding to the input arguments you mentioned. In this case, just implement two methods, with the same name, having adequate and minimal set of arguments which return objects of different classes. Using this approach you may drop "type" as well

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an Abstract Factory not a Factory Method. Your Abstract Factory will create Parts. You then create concrete Factories that derive from the abstract factory for each of the parts you want to create. This way, you can drop the type checking as each concrete factory only knows about its part. You've almost got this by inheriting from PartFactory.

The only problem with this approach is that different parts need different pieces of data for construction. This wouldn't be possible behind an abstract Create() method. It could be handled in the constructor of the concrete factories but this means your, sort of, stuck with those values for the lifetime of the factory.